# Case statement with alias

Tags: sql-server, case

Looking to get a case statement to work in this script. First time trying it and not sure what's wrong with it.

```
SELECT DocumentDest.Keycode  AS [Acct #],
       Customer.Name,
       DocumentDest.Emails,
       Case
           Customer.Freq AS [Weekly or Monthly]
           When 'W' then 'Weekly'
           When 'M' then 'Monthly'
           Else 'None'
       End
FROM       DocumentDest
INNER JOIN Customer ON DocumentDest.Keycode = Customer.KeyCode
WHERE  (DocumentDest.Type = 'cus') AND (DocumentDest.[Document] IN ('stmt', 'wstmt'))
```

Comment: Its not MySQL. Do you mean SQL-SERVER

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Steve: I changed a mismatched double quote to a single quote. I'm assuming that this is not relevant to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias `Weekly or Monthly` must not appear in the middle of the `CASE` statement: This is a SQL-Server version, for MySql form aliases accordingly.

```
SELECT 
      DocumentDest.Keycode AS [Acct #], 
      Customer.Name, 
      DocumentDest.Emails, 
      Case Customer.Freq When 'W' then 'Weekly' When 'M' then 'Monthly' Else 'None'      
      End AS [Weekly or Monthly] 
    FROM DocumentDest INNER JOIN Customer 
    ON DocumentDest.Keycode = Customer.KeyCode 
    WHERE DocumentDest.Type = 'cus' 
    AND DocumentDest[Document IN ('stmt', 'wstmt')
```

Comment: So the Case statement also creates the Alias. Got it. Thank you.